# How can I record the audio output using sox?

Tags: sound, 20.04, audio-recording, sox

I want to record the output of Google Text to speech to a mp3 file. I need a command that I can use in Terminal. I read `sox` can record audio, however don't know how to set up it to record the output audio of my computer. I also prefer to automatically stop recording if the audio output was silent for at least 3 seconds... Any other tool for this purpose is acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to extract the name of output device:

To do this, you can install the following modules:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-utils lame mpg123
```

And run:

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:' -e 'index' -e 'Speakers'
```

The output could be like this:

```
index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
index: 23
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-surround71>
```

After you found the name, you can run the following command to record the output to an mp3 file:

```
parec -d alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor | lame -r -V0 - out.mp3
```

Or using `sox` you can do the following, however I found the first solution more robust:

```
sox -t pulseaudio alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor -t mp3 test.mp3
```

However, if you want to automatically start and stop recording you can run:

```
sox -v 5 -t pulseaudio alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor -t mp3 test.mp3 silence 1 0.1 3% 1 3.0 3%
```

Or using `parec`:

```
parec -d alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor | sox -t raw -b 16 -e signed -c 2 -r 44100 - test.ogg silence 1 0.1 3% 1 3.0 3%
```

It begins recording when a sounds sent to the speaker and stops if nothing is received after 3 seconds. for more information about sox refer to [sox man page in linux](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sox)

Comment: Please explain a bit and break down the options of the command for other readers (which is what this site is for). How can the reader find the argument `lsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor`? Will that be the same on every computer?

Answer (score 0):

Idk why but none of the solutions worked for me.
I finally solved my problem by installing: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/audio-voice-recorder/deadjnaenmndpdpakgchpbedlcdmmoai
(But I need to record the output's audio from chrome only). I leave the comment because someone is in the same situation.